# How to convert string date to specific format?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, luxon

I am trying to get date from string in specific format like:

```js
    const format = 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm';
    const dt = "2021-03-11T22:00:00.000Z"; // expecting "03/11/2021 22:00"
    
    console.log(moment(dt).format(format)); // but getting "03/Th/yyyy 23:00"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I tried js date, moment, luxon and I don't understand how to make this :(
I suspect that `000Z` made problem but this is date I get.

Comment: It's likely you're using incorrect formatting? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ --- Try the format `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm`?

Comment: Did you try the format string `MM/DD/yyyy HH:mm` uppercase `DD`

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: From the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), `dd` means "Day of week in Su Mo Tu... format", and `yyyy` does not exist. So you are getting `03/Th/yyyy`, makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between Moment.js and Luxon is the case of the format keys. Please review the key/token tables.

- [Moment.js / String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
- [Luxon / Table of tokens](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html#table-of-tokens)

**Note:** Moment.js has been [deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) in favor of the team's newer library Luxon and other ECMA Script standards that are being introduced in [ECMA-402](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/). If you are considering using Moment.js now, just switch over to Luxon.

---

If you are using Luxon, you can call `.toUTC()` right before you format the date. Make sure your day of month (`dd`) and year (`yyyy`) format keys are lower-case.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

const
  format = 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm',
  dt = "2021-03-11T22:00:00.000Z";

console.log(DateTime.fromISO(dt).toUTC().toFormat(format)); // 03/11/2021 22:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.26.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

If you are using Moment.js, you can call `.utc()` right before you format the date. Make sure your day of month (`DD`) and year (`YYYY`) format keys are upper-case.

```js
const
  format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
  dt = "2021-03-11T22:00:00.000Z";

console.log(moment(dt).utc().format(format)); // 03/11/2021 22:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually this solved problem thanks. I was wrong in forming a question as I have got example in luxon and tried to fix with momentjs. I was not aware of different string formats. Thanks this works.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is wrong, it should be: `'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'`.

Then, if your date comes with `':000Z'`, you should remove it with the `substring()` method.

Working code:

```js
const format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm';
const dateString = "2021-03-11T22:00:00:000Z";
const date = dateString.substring(0, dateString.length - 5);

console.log(moment(date).format(format)); // prints 03/11/2021 22:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `YYYY` instead of `yyyy` and `DD` instead of `dd` to get the expected result.
By the way, I suggest [using another library than Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), like dayjs for instance.